# If $G$ is a finite group in which every subgroup has a normal complement, then $G$ is nilpotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

Problem from an old prelim exam:

> If $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup, then a normal complement to
> $H$ in $G$ is a normal subgroup $N\trianglelefteq G$ such that
> $N\cap H = \{1\}$ and $N H = G$. Show that if $G$ is a finite group in which
> every subgroup has a normal complement, then $G$ is nilpotent.

My first thought is to use the theorem (6.3.2 in Dummit & Foote) that $G$ is nilpotent iff $H<N_G(H)$ for every proper subgroup $H<G$.

Thus, let $H<G$ be proper; it suffices to find $g\in G\setminus H$ such that $H^g=H$. The assumption gives $N\trianglelefteq G$ such that $G\cong N\ltimes H$, so, in order that $H^g=H$, we need $g=(n,k)$ such that for every $h\in H$ we have

$$\begin{align}
g (1, h) g^{-1}&=(n, k) (1, h) (n, k)^{-1}\\
&=(n (k\cdot h\cdot k^{-1}\cdot n^{-1}),khk^{-1})\\
&\in H.
\end{align}$$

That is, we need nontrivial $n$ such that $n=h^k\cdot n$ for every $h$. Clearly, such an $n$ need not exist for every choice of $N,H$ (for example, $N\ltimes \text{Aut}(N)$), so I guess we need to apply the normal complement assumption to a subgroup other than $H$ itself. But which one? Or should we use a different approach entirely?

Comment: You only need all of the Sylow subgroups to have normal complements in order to deduce nilpotence. By taking intersections of normal complements of Sylow subgroups we find that all Sylow subgroups are normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assumptions actually imply that $G$ must be abelian. One can prove this without the assumption that $G$ is finite.

Let $x\in G$ and let $N_x$ be a normal complement to
the cyclic subgroup
$\langle x\rangle$. By the Second Isomorphism Theorem,
$G/N_x\cong \langle x\rangle$. Since $\langle x\rangle$
is disjoint from $N_x$, the intersection $I:=\bigcap N_x$
of all $N_x$'s is disjoint from every cyclic subgroup of $G$,
hence equals $\{1\}$. This yields
$$G\cong G/I=G/\bigcap N_x \leq \prod (G/N_x)\cong
\prod \langle x\rangle.$$
The cyclic groups $\langle x\rangle$ are abelian,
and abelianness is inherited by
products and subgroups, so $G$ is abelian. \\\